# Auctex preview broken due to Preview-Ghostscript problems

Tags: auctex

I got the following error when I was running Auctex-preview.

```
Tex Output exited as expected with code 1 at Wed Nov 29 21:31:55
Running `Preview-PDF2DSC' with ``pdf2dsc _region_.pdf _region_.prv/tmpeuztCi/preview.dsc''

Preview-PDF2DSC finished at Wed Nov 29 21:31:55
Running `Preview-Ghostscript' with ``/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/rungs -sOutputFile\=_region_.prv/tmpeuztCi/pr1-\%d.png -q -dDELAYSAFER -dNOPAUSE -DNOPLATFONTS -dPrinted -dTextAlphaBits\=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits\=4 -sDEVICE\=png16m -rinfxinf -dDELAYBIND''

Preview-Ghostscript exited abnormally with code 255 at Wed Nov 29 21:31:55
Unrecoverable error: limitcheck in .putdeviceprops

Preview-Ghostscript exited abnormally with code 255
```

I was wondering if anybody else has experienced this error and knows how to fix it?

Comment: Can you add a minimal example to your question?  That would help others to reproduce the issue.

Comment: And the part `-rinfxinf` looks wrong.  Those `inf` should be floats for the resolution, so something like `-r129.34x129.751`.